# Render embedded image in PDF using Flying-Saucer from html

Tags: java, pdf-generation, embedded-resource, flying-saucer, xhtmlrenderer

I have an xhtml document that I'm turning into a PDF using flyingsaucer. The xhtml has several  tags that have a base64 encoded images inline.  The source of the xhtml is dynamic so the structure of where the image tags are can vary. This is a sample of what the tag looks like:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAagAAAEuCAYAAADbW4YFAAAgAElEQVR4Aex9CYBdRZ ...
```

When I look at the html in a browser, the image appears correctly, however, the img element doesn't get rendered in the final PDF.  Here is how I'm rendering it out to create the PDF.

```
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocument(builder.parse(source), "");
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(response.getOutputStream(),true);
```

Can anyone let me know what approach I should take to accomplish this?  I saw [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316607/render-image-from-servlet-in-flyingsaucer-generated-pdf), however, I'm using inline images so I can't see how I can accomplish this using Edd's solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a feature request to make data-url for images work directly in Flying Saucer: https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/issues/detail?id=202

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can use the approach given here: [Render image from servlet in flyingsaucer generated pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316607/render-image-from-servlet-in-flyingsaucer-generated-pdf)

Where Edd has:

```
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = ...;
            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
            Image image = Image.getInstance(bytes);
```

In Edd's case the image is coming from a remote source (he skips over that bit with `input = ...;`). In your case you just want to read it from your Base64 encoded data (the text after the `base64,`. First use a [Base64 decoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java) to get the binary data, into a `byte[]` or Stream, you can then use [Java ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) to create the image from your bytes and follow Edd's approach to get the image into the PDF. Kudos to Edd here (upvote for sure!).

Answer (score 8):

Flying-Saucer supports the data: protocol natively. All you have to do is register a protocol handler:

```
-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.xhtmlrenderer.protocols
```

No need for servlets whatsoverver.

Comment: Do you have a link for how protocol handlers are registered?