# css styles is not visible when downloading the pdf file using thymleaf html template in java

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using thymleaf html template. When I preview the page the styling looks good. When I download the pdf, I don't see any CSS styles applied. The pdf contains content only not the style which I have applied.

// download generation code

Pdf generation code [link](https://github.com/gustavoponce7/pdfgenerator/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gpch/pdfgenerator/service/PdfService.java) which I referred and used the same

// sample code

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
        <title>Profile Preview</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css"></link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper-css/0.4.1/paper.css"></link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
    <style>
    @page { size: A4 }
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    td, th {
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    
    tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #dddddd
    }
    
    </style>
    </head>        
    <body class="A4">
    <div class ="preview">
    <section class="sheet">
    <div class="logo">
    <img th:src="@{/images/logo.png}" />
    </div> 
     <h4 style="font-size: 1em; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1em">
     <p>Age: <span th:text="${profile.basicInfo.age}"></span></p>
     <p>D.O.B: <span th:text="${profile.basicInfo.birthDate}"></span></p>
     <p>Gender: <span th:text="${profile.basicInfo.gender.toString()}"></span></p>
     <p>Education: <span th:text="${profile.professionalInfo.educationDetail}"></span></p>
     </h4>
  <table>
<tr>
<th colspan="4" style="text-align:center; background-color: #6c3c81; color:white; font-weight: bold">Partner Preference Information</th>
  </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </section> 
    </div>
    <button class="button" onClick="window.print();this.style.display='none'">Print</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

// server side code

```
GetMapping("/{id}/download")
    public void download(@PathVariable("id") String id, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            Path file = Paths.get(profilePdfService.generatePdf(id).getAbsolutePath());
            if (Files.exists(file)) {
                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getFileName());
                Files.copy(file, response.getOutputStream());
                response.getOutputStream().flush();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: CSS has nothing to do with PDF. You'll need to post much more information and code to show what you are doing.

Comment: @RoToRa Update code. Refer above

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using Flying Saucer for rendering in PDF format the generated Thymeleaf template HTML.

There can be several issues here.

First, you need to provide a proper XHTML document to Flying Source. For this task, you can use JTidy to convert the rendered Thymeleaf template to XHTML: it maybe does not work in a very complicated HTML, but it very likely will in your use case.

There are a lot of versions of JTidy. Sorry, in a previous version of the answer I provided you a reference to an outdated one I previously used, that maybe does not work for HTML5 as your need. Please, use the following dependency instead, based on a brand new JTidy [project](https://github.com/jtidy/jtidy):

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.jtidy</groupId>
  <artifactId>jtidy</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

For example, in the source code of the `PdfService` class you indicated in the question, modify the `generatePdf` method as follows:

```java
public File generatePdf() throws IOException, DocumentException {
  Context context = getContext();
  String html = loadAndFillTemplate(context);
  String xhtml = convertToXhtml(html);
  return renderPdf(xhtml);
}
```

Where `convertToXhtml` can look like (is an updated version of the previous one adapted for the new JTidy library version):

```java
// Necessary imports, among others
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.tidy.Tidy;

//...

private String convertToXhtml(String html) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
  Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
  tidy.setXHTML(true);
  tidy.setIndentContent(true);
  tidy.setPrintBodyOnly(true);
  tidy.setInputEncoding("UTF-8");
  tidy.setOutputEncoding("UTF-8");
  tidy.setSmartIndent(true);
  tidy.setShowWarnings(false);
  tidy.setQuiet(true);
  tidy.setTidyMark(false);

  Document htmlDOM = tidy.parseDOM(new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes()), null);

  OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  tidy.pprint(htmlDOM, out);
  return out.toString();
}
```

See how the page looks like after performing this process: you are applying a lot of inline styles and the PDF should look better.

Also, instead of using external CDN distributed stylesheets, use a local copy of them, accessible to your application as the resource identified as [`PDF_RESOURCES`](https://github.com/gustavoponce7/pdfgenerator/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gpch/pdfgenerator/service/PdfService.java#L19) in the source code of the `PdfService` class.

As you can see in the [implementation](https://github.com/gustavoponce7/pdfgenerator/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gpch/pdfgenerator/service/PdfService.java#L36-L46) of the `renderPdf` of that class, it is being used as the base URL to look for the different resources referenced in the page.

Finally, pay attention to your logo: perhaps you will need to provide some custom implementation of [ReplacedElementFactory](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer/blob/master/flying-saucer-core/src/main/java/org/xhtmlrenderer/extend/ReplacedElementFactory.java) for that purpose. Please, consider read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477065/using-flying-saucer-to-render-images-to-pdf-in-memory) or [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316607/render-image-from-servlet-in-flyingsaucer-generated-pdf/10336163#10336163) SO questions, I think they can be helpful.

Following these steps, with minor tweaks, you should be able to obtain something like the following PDF:

[image]

If Flying Saucer does not fulfill your requirements, please, take a look at any headless browser, for instance, [PhantomJS](https://phantomjs.org), to perform the conversion.

Comment: I tried above your code but Still facing the same issue

Comment: I am sorry to hear that, it should have worked. Do you get any error? Do you experiment any improvement in the way the information is printed? Please, how do you actually print the document to PDF? In your code, I can only see `window.print()`, but with no reference to any server side code involved in the operation. I assume you perform some kind of HTTP call to the server side of your application.

Comment: It's showing error in this line     <!DOCTYPE HTML> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file. But I have checked the end of the html it's working fine. The layout works fine preview page, but css getting missed in download pdf and print view. Even I am getting error while hitting download interface alone.

Comment: @ jccampanero I have attached the server-side code also.Refer above

Comment: Hi @selvi. Sorry for the late reply. Thank you very much for updating the question. I am sorry to hear that you are facing problems while processing the HTML, I suppose, when trying tidying the HTML. I update the answer with a more up to date library version. Please, can you try again and see it the error is gone? Thank you, sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: jccampanero What is the import of this two lines . I was trying to import apache, Isn't it? Document htmlDOM = tidy.parseDOM(new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes()), null);

  OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();.

Comment: Hi @selvi. Please, see the updated answer.