# JSoup not able to get links from html

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jsoup

I'm trying to get links from html of a site but unable to do so using Jsoup.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="anime_muti_link">
    <ul>
  <li><div class="doamin">Domain</div><div class="link">Link</div></li>
  <li class="anime">
    <a href="#" class="active" rel="1" data-video="example.com" ><div class="server m1">Server m1</div><span>Watch This Link</span></a>
  </li>
    
  <li class="anime">
    <a href="#" rel="1" data-video="example.com" ><div class="server m1">Server m2</div><span>Watch This Link</span></a>
  </li>
  
              <li class="xstreamcdn">
      <a href="#" rel="29" data-video="example.com">Xstreamcdn</div><span>Watch This Link</span></a>
    </li>
          <li class="mixdrop">
      <a href="#" rel="7" data-video="example.com"><div class="server mixdrop">Mixdrop</div><span>Watch This Link</span></a>
    </li>
          <li class="streamsb">
      <a href="#" rel="13" data-video="example.com">StreamSB</div><span>Watch This Link</span></a>
    </li>
          <li class="doodstream">
      <a href="#" rel="14" data-video="example.com">Doodstream</div><span>Watch This Link</span></a>
    </li>
  
</ul>
</div>
```

This is the android code that I wrote which doesn't seem to work:

```
try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
                Elements content = doc.getElementsByClass("anime_muti_link");
                Elements links = content.select("a");

                String[] urls = new String[links.size()];
                for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
                    urls[i] = links.get(i).attr("data-video");
                    if (!urls[i].startsWith("https://")) {
                        urls[i] = "https:" + urls[i];
                    }
                }
                arrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(urls));
                Log.d("CALLING_URL", "Links: " + Arrays.toString(urls));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }
```

Can someone please help me with this? Thanks

Edit: Basically I'm trying to get those 6 links and add them to my list to use it within the app.

Edit 2:

So I found another HTML that can seems better:

```
<div class="heading-servers">
     <span><i class="fa fa-signal"></i> Servers</span>
     <ul class="servers">
      <li data-vs="https://example.com" class="server server-active" style="display: block;" onclick="return loadIframe('ifrm', this.getAttribute('data-vs'));">Netu</li>
      <li data-vs="https://example.com" class="server" style="display: block;" onclick="return loadIframe('ifrm', this.getAttribute('data-vs'));">VideoVard</li>
      <li data-vs="https://example.com" class="server" style="display: block;" onclick="return loadIframe('ifrm', this.getAttribute('data-vs'));">Doodstream</li>
      <li data-vs="https://example.com" class="server" style="display: block;" onclick="return loadIframe('ifrm', this.getAttribute('data-vs'));">Okstream</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, in this `li` definition you are including a nested `div`:

```html
<li class="xstreamcdn">
      <a href="#" rel="29" data-video="example.com">Xstreamcdn</div><span>Watch This Link</span></a>
    </li>
```

This is causing that the variable content, the HTML fragment with class `anime_muti_link`, to look like:

```html
<div class="anime_muti_link"> 
 <ul> 
  <li>
   <div class="doamin">
    Domain
   </div>
   <div class="link">
    Link
   </div></li> 
  <li class="anime"> <a href="#" class="active" rel="1" data-video="example.com">
    <div class="server m1">
     Server m1
    </div><span>Watch This Link</span></a> </li> 
  <li class="anime"> <a href="#" rel="1" data-video="example.com">
    <div class="server m1">
     Server m2
    </div><span>Watch This Link</span></a> </li> 
  <li class="xstreamcdn"> <a href="#" rel="29" data-video="example.com">Xstreamcdn</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

A similar result will be obtained even if you tidy your HTML. I used this code from one of my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64532755/css-styles-is-not-visible-when-downloading-the-pdf-file-using-thymleaf-html-temp/66068741#66068741):

```java
Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
tidy.setXHTML(true);
tidy.setIndentContent(true);
tidy.setPrintBodyOnly(true);
tidy.setInputEncoding("UTF-8");
tidy.setOutputEncoding("UTF-8");
tidy.setSmartIndent(true);
tidy.setShowWarnings(false);
tidy.setQuiet(true);
tidy.setTidyMark(false);

org.w3c.dom.Document htmlDOM = tidy.parseDOM(new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes()), null);

OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
tidy.pprint(htmlDOM, out);
String tidiedHtml = out.toString();
// System.out.println(tidiedHtml);

Document document = Jsoup.parse(tidiedHtml);
Elements content = document.getElementsByClass("anime_muti_link");
System.out.println(content);
```

And this is why you are finding only three anchors.

Please, try correcting your HTML or selecting the anchor tag as the document level instead:

```java
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
// Elements content = document.getElementsByClass("anime_muti_link");
// System.out.println(content);
Elements links = document.select("a");

String[] urls = new String[links.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
  urls[i] = links.get(i).attr("data-video");
  if (!urls[i].startsWith("https://")) {
    urls[i] = "https://" + urls[i];
  }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(urls));
```

If the result obtained contains undesired links, perhaps you can try narrowing the selector used, something like:

```java
document.select(".anime_muti_link a")
```

If this doesn't work, another possible alternative could be selecting the anchor elements with a `data-video` attribute, `a[data-video]`:

```java
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements videoLinks = document.select("a[data-video]");

String[] urls = new String[videoLinks.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < videoLinks.size(); i++) {
  urls[i] = videoLinks.get(i).attr("data-video");
  if (!urls[i].startsWith("https://")) {
    urls[i] = "https://" + urls[i];
  }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(urls));
```

---

With your new test case, you can obtain the desired information with a very similar code:

```java
String html = "<div class=\"heading-servers\">\n" +
    "     <span><i class=\"fa fa-signal\"></i> Servers</span>\n" +
    "     <ul class=\"servers\">\n" +
    "      <li data-vs=\"https://example.com\" class=\"server server-active\" style=\"display: block;\" onclick=\"return loadIframe('ifrm', this.getAttribute('data-vs'));\">Netu</li>\n" +
    "      <li data-vs=\"https://example.com\" class=\"server\" style=\"display: block;\" onclick=\"return loadIframe('ifrm', this.getAttribute('data-vs'));\">VideoVard</li>\n" +
    "      <li data-vs=\"https://example.com\" class=\"server\" style=\"display: block;\" onclick=\"return loadIframe('ifrm', this.getAttribute('data-vs'));\">Doodstream</li>\n" +
    "      <li data-vs=\"https://example.com\" class=\"server\" style=\"display: block;\" onclick=\"return loadIframe('ifrm', this.getAttribute('data-vs'));\">Okstream</li>\n" +
    "     </ul>\n" +
    "    </div>";

Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements videoLinks = document.select("div.heading-servers ul.servers li.server");

String[] urls = new String[videoLinks.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < videoLinks.size(); i++) {
  urls[i] = videoLinks.get(i).attr("data-vs");
  if (!urls[i].startsWith("https://")) {
    urls[i] = "https://" + urls[i];
  }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.asList(urls));
```

The most important part is the definition of the [selector](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) that should be applied to the parsed document, `div.heading-servers ul.servers li.server` in our case.

I provided a selector with many fragments, but depending on the actual use HTML it could be simplified with `ul.servers li.server` or even `li.server`.

Comment: I can't change the HTML as that's not my website. I'll try your other solution, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome @MegganSam, I hope it helps. I updated the answer to provide feedback about how to possibly narrow the selector in case you obtain undesired links. I haven't tested this last update. I hope it helps.

Comment: @MegganSam Were you able to test the proposed solution? Did it work?

Comment: I did try, yes. Unfortunately, it doesn't work :(

Comment: I am sorry to hear that. I suppose it has to do with processing the whole HTML document. I updated the answer trying providing another alternative. Please, could you try? I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but seems like the HTML itself isn't written well so I've edited my question with another one that has child classes too so can you maybe help me with that? I tried you solution on the new one but that doesn't work either sadly

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, I agree with you Meggan, probably there should be something wrong in the HTML. Regarding your edition, I updated my answer with a possible solution. Please, could you try?

Comment: It worked, omg, thanks a ton!!!

Comment: That is great Meggan!! I am very happy to hear that it worked properly!!